# Best practice to write minimal code when using vuejs vee-validate with composition api in vuejs3

Tags: vue.js, vee-validate

I have gone through the composition api docs for vee-validate, and I can definitely get my validation working on my forms if I follow the pattern described in their docs.

I don't feel comfortable however doing it as documented there, as I just feel I'm writing too much code for each form, and I do not want to repeat myself.

So I've been experimeting a bit with how I can optimise this, and this is what we currently came up with, but I'm a bit stuck now.

You can see the code example on https://codesandbox.io/s/restless-star-1qwgb, but I'll walk you through.

Consider we want to create a form for creating a new Invoice.
An invoice is typically composed of the `Invoice` model with a number of `InvoiceElements` attached to it. (the invoice lines)

In our vueJs codebase, we have javascript classes representing each model that we need to work with, so you'll find a class `Invoice` and a class `InvoiceElement`, both extending `BaseModel` which already providers some basic functionality.

On each mode, we have defined a static method returning a `yup` validation schema, e.g.:

```js
import * as yup from "yup";
import BaseModel from "./BaseModel";
import InvoiceElement from "./InvoiceElement";

export default class Invoice extends BaseModel {
  static get validationSchema() {
    return yup.object().shape({
      due_date: yup.date().min(new Date()).default("2021-09-30"),
      reference: yup.string(),
      elements: yup
        .array()
        .of(InvoiceElement.validationSchema)
        .default([InvoiceElement.validationSchema.getDefault()])
    });
  }
}
```

As you can see, we also define default values for each of the schema fields.
This allows us to do the following in our form component:

```js
setup() {
    let { handleSubmit, errors, values } = useForm({
      validationSchema: Invoice.validationSchema,
      initialValues: Invoice.validationSchema.getDefault(),
      validateOnMount: false,
    });

    let addLine = () => {
      values.elements.push(InvoiceElement.validationSchema.getDefault());
    };

    let submitForm = handleSubmit((values) => {
      alert("form was valid and we submit data here");
    });

    return {
      values,
      errors,
      addLine,
      submitForm,
    };
  }
```

Okay - I'm very happy with this as we now have:

- `values` which is reactive and I can just bind to my inputs using ```
- `errors` which has my errors

When I submit the form, it correctly triggers vee-validate's `handleSubmit()` method and my errors get correctly updated.

My main issue with this approach now is how to trigger the validation of the fields when they get updated.  The main goal is to avoid having to write too much code using the `useField()` composable.

I know I'm not following the proposed pattern, but it just kept feeling as if we were writing too much code, and we seem quite close to a good pattern, but I just don't get the last bits...

Maybe someone on here does though :-)

Answer (score 0):

Generally, the docs are only meant to show you "how it works", but I do agree that `useField` is very verbose if used incorrectly. Using it for models isn't the intended use-case.

For example:

```js
// Very verbose and not the intended use-case
const { value: email } = useField(...);
const { value: password } = useField(...);
```

The main purpose of `useField` is to help create input components that can be validated, that if you are willing to couple your form components with vee-validate which I find reasonable in 80% of situations.

To try to answer your issue, since you want to avoid using `useField` you could actually make use of the other `useXXX` functions called [composition helpers](https://vee-validate.logaretm.com/v4/api/composition-helpers). Like `useValidateField` which creates a function for you that can validate any field given it was created in a child of a `useForm` component.

```js
const validate = useValidateField('fieldName');
validate(); // triggers validation on the field
```

Comment: Thanks!  It's still very verbose to me, so we switched to just write an implementation with using yup directly, which in the end requires much less code for each form.  Absolutely appreciate your library, but having to do something for each individual field just feels too verbose for us.  Your suggestion still requires me to do that for each field where we want to be able to just "validate the form data" without having to explicitely add logic for each field.